# Transfer file from ios App to a App running on a PC

Tags: ios, file-transfer

My iOS app creates files in its documents folder when it is running

I need to write a App on a PC(and eventually on a Mac) so that when the iOS app is running and the PC app is running - the files in the iOS Documents folder should be visible and available for download from the iOS to the PC over a WiFi network.

Some other posts recommend using iTunes or iCloud however my requirements state that

- I cannot force the user to use iTunes to transfer files
- No iCloud or DropBox
- No third party sign up a new account for a web service

i.e. Need a dedicated client App on the PC/Mac

Is there a **standard framework** available to accomplish this?

A good example is what the iTalk voice recorder does.

Comment: Did try to find iExplorer open-source alternative to see how it works ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you should take a look at Apple's Bonjour service. These documents might provide a good starting point:

[Bonjour Overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NetServices/Introduction.html)

[Introduction to NSNetServices and CFNetServices Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/NSNetServiceProgGuide/Introduction.html)

Also, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477602/bonjour-for-iphone) from Brad Larson you'll find some more information about Bonjour

And here's an example project from Apple showing the usage of Bonjour: [BonjourWeb](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/BonjourWeb/Introduction/Intro.html)